# HMHomeManager homes is empty

Tags: ios, swift, homekit

I'm creating an instance of HMHomeManager, registering the delegate, waiting until homeManegerDidUpdateHomes() is called, but when I read manager.homes, it returns an empty array.

I tried checking the following:

- Adding the NSHomeKitUsageDescription key to my info.plist
- Removing and adding access to HomeKit for my app in the Settings app
- Deleting my home in the Home app and recreating it

Nothing seems to work, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it's not enough to enable all those settings. You also need to go to the Capabilities tab of your project, and enable HomeKit. Otherwise `manager.homes.count` will be zero, and `manager.primaryHome` will be `nil`.